# Mapping points on the unit circle

Tags: graphics

I have a set of points P that are evenly spaced on a square grid of length 1.

I would like to map these points to the circle of radius 1 as nicely as possible, while preserving relative positions as much as possible. That is, the points in the square grid should map to the points in the unit circle.

How can this be done in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Assuming that a map is a function, by what criterion should the mapping be done?  Closest (highlighted) point on the unit circle?

Comment: Do the circle and square have the same center? (e.g. {0,0})?

Comment: Do you mean [`Circle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Circle.html) or [`Disk`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Disk.html)?

Answer (score 13):

Your question is a little vague, but one possible mapping from a square to a circle is the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x^\prime\\y^\prime\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{2}}\\y\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

This transformation wrapped into a *Mathematica* function:

```
transformation[points_] := {#[[1]] Sqrt[1 - (#[[2]]^2/2)],
       #[[2]] Sqrt[1 - (#[[1]]^2/2)]} & /@ # & /@ points;
```

And a little demonstration:

```
points = Table[{a, b}, {a, -1, 1, 0.2}, {b, -1, 1, 0.2}];

Show[
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}],
 ListPlot[Flatten[points, 1], AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
Show[
 Graphics[{Thick, Circle[]}],
 ListPlot[Flatten[transformation[points], 1], AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: square-circle mapping]

Comment: Nice answer, but no need for `Show` and `ListPlot`.  Suggest `Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[None], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[Flatten[points, 1]]}]` and `Graphics[{Thick, Circle[], Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[Flatten[transformation@points, 1]]}]`

Answer (score 3):

I've used the Schwarz-Christoffel conformal map from the square to the disk plenty of times on this site (search around!); here's how to use it for this question:

```
pts = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1, 1/5}, {y, 1, -1, -1/5}], 1];

{Graphics[{Directive[AbsolutePointSize[3], ColorData[61, 8]], Point[pts]},
          Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Before"], 
 Graphics[{Directive[AbsolutePointSize[3], ColorData[61, 8]], 
           Point[pts /. {x_, y_} :> 
           With[{ω = N[3 Beta[5/4, 5/4]/2]}, 
                Through[{Re, Im}[JacobiSN[ω (x + I y), 1/2]
                                 JacobiDC[ω (x + I y), 1/2]]]]]},
          Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "After"]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: square-to-disk conformal map]